# Remove specific li element from list when parsing page with simple_html_dom

Tags: php, arrays, simple-html-dom

I am pulling some page with simple_html_dom and on a page there is a list of `ul li` elements which I need to pull, but problem is that these are basically video tags, which are combined with other elements that I don't need in that.

Here is an example of original page source:

```
<ul id="video-tags">
            <li>Uploader: </li>
    <li class="profile_name"><a href="/profiles/sarasubmit">Sarasubmit</a>.</li>
            <li><em>Tagged: </em></li>
                    <li><a href="/tags/makeup">makeup</a>, </li>
                            <li><a href="/tags/cosmetic">cosmetic</a>, </li>
                            <li><a href="/tags/liner">liner</a>, </li>
                            <li><a href="/tags/fresh">fresh</a>, </li>
                            <li><a href="/tags/girls">girls</a>, </li>
                            <li><a href="/tags/fashion">fashion</a>, </li>
                    <li>more <a href="/tags/"><strong>tags</strong></a>.</li>
  </ul>
```

So when I pull the page I tried using this to get the tags.

```
 $get_tags = $video_page_url->find('ul[id="video-tags"]', 0);

$post_tags_arr = array();
foreach($get_tags->find('a') as $tag) {
$post_tags_arr[] = $tag->plaintext;
}
$post_tags = implode(', ', $post_tags_arr);
```

This way I get all the a elements inside `li` and output text, but since profile name is also link and more tags is also link I get that 2 also so I end up with this.

```
sarasubmit, makeup, cosmetic, liner, fresh, girls, fashion, tags
```

Is there a way that I can just strip out tags and remove other elements so I end up like this:

```
 makeup, cosmetic, liner, fresh, girls, fashion,
```

Edit: Just to mention, username is not constant so it's changing depending of who uploaded video, and also some videos don't have tags at all, and some have more or less tags. So things are dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
foreach($get_tags->find('li[!class] a') as $tag) {
    if($tag->plaintext != 'tags') $post_tags_arr[] = $tag->plaintext;
}
```

Instead of this:

```
foreach($get_tags->find('a') as $tag)
    $post_tags_arr[] = $tag->plaintext;
}
```

**Update:** I've tested:

```
$htmlStr = '<ul id="video-tags">
    <li>Uploader: </li>
    <li class="profile_name"><a href="/profiles/sarasubmit">Sarasubmit</a>.</li>
    <li><em>Tagged: </em></li>
    <li><a href="/tags/makeup">makeup</a>, </li>
    <li><a href="/tags/cosmetic">cosmetic</a>, </li>
    <li><a href="/tags/liner">liner</a>, </li>
    <li><a href="/tags/fresh">fresh</a>, </li>
    <li><a href="/tags/girls">girls</a>, </li>
    <li><a href="/tags/fashion">fashion</a>, </li>
    <li>more <a href="/tags/"><strong>tags</strong></a>.</li>
</ul>';

$html = str_get_html($htmlStr);
foreach($html->find('li[!class] a') as $tag) {
    if($tag->plaintext != 'tags') $post_tags_arr[] = $tag->plaintext;
}
print_r($post_tags_arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => makeup
    [1] => cosmetic
    [2] => liner
    [3] => fresh
    [4] => girls
    [5] => fashion
)
```

So, try this:

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->find('li[!class] a') as $tag) {
    if($tag->plaintext != 'tags') $post_tags_arr[] = $tag->plaintext;
}
```

[Check the manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm).

Comment: It doesn't work, for some reason it returns nothing.

Comment: Can you gimme the `link/url` of the page that you are scrapping ?

Comment: Yea i also tried that but it's the same, i read the manual and apparently ! should exclude that li element but it returns empty tags. And i would rather not share link because it's an adult website. And the html of site is as i posted, i just changed tag names from adult to safe. And when i try 'li a' or just 'a' it works fine but returns all li elements.'li[class!="profile_name"] a' returns empty.